# Error getting extended BSON for document while importing json document in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, bson

Problem:

I have a json like this.

```
{"engine1": {"status": "0"}, "_id": {"$oid": "00004ab3fda51b600a43906706b3fa96"}, "behaviour": "not_found"}
```

Here i have created a mongo collection which i want to import these jsons.Now when iam trying to import the json iam facing the following error.

```
nsadmin@admmin:/dev/lab_data/lab_export$ mongoimport --db dbname --collection lab_data --file 00004ab3fda51b600a43906706b3fa96.json
2018-07-23T08:38:54.983+0000    connected to: localhost
2018-07-23T08:38:54.983+0000    Failed: error getting extended BSON for document #0: expected $oid field to contain 24 hexadecimal character
2018-07-23T08:38:54.983+0000    imported 0 documents
```

How to solve this issue?Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"_id": {"$oid": "00004ab3fda51b600a43906706b3fa96"}

this part is creating issue here. Remove it and you will be able to import all doc.

Comment: length of _id you have provided is 32. reduce it to 24 then you will be able to add the same.